# Can Ubuntu JeOS work with Xen?

Tags: server, xen

Can I install Ubuntu as *Minimal Virtual Install* (formarly called [Ubuntu JeOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_JeOS)<sup>1</sup>) on Xen hypervisor or not?

Does it only support KVM and VMware?

<sub>1. Ubuntu JeOS a version of Ubuntu that can be installed with the Server CD selecting "Minimal virtual machine" at the install screen.</sub>

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini - none of the download links in the JeOS wiki appears to be working.  Looks unsupported at first glance.

Comment: @fossfreedom: the wiki page is outdated. As I said, "JeOS" is an ancient name. What was called JeOS is now known as the "minimal virtual installation" of the server CD. The `linux-virtual` package that you see in the official repos belongs to it.

Comment: It took me a while, but eventually I found the [announcment](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2008-October/026621.html)! _JeOS has also been renamed to Minimal Install_

Comment: So, what version of Ubuntu are you using? the old one still named "JeOS" or a new supported version with the minimal install?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu minimal virtual install differs from the standard server install in two ways:

1. lesser packages are installed;
2. a different kernel is installed.

Before Oneiric, the kernel was the one provided by the *linux-image-*-virtual* packages. Nowadays, the kernel used by the minimal install is *linux-image-*-generic*. Instead, standard server and desktop installs use both *linux-image-*-generic* and *linux-image-extra-*-generic*.

All of this to say that if the minimal install does not work, it's because it lacks some drivers and modules that are shipped with the *extra* package.

So, the question is: are the drivers sufficient to run Ubuntu on Xen? I don't know and I can't try at the moment. If `vmbuilder` does not let you use Ubuntu Minimal with Xen, it's a different matter.

What I can say is that Launchpad PPA builders and Amazon EC2 run on Xen, and I am pretty sure that neither of them are using the *extra* kernel package.